# Не выводятся последние ключ и значение

Tags: python, функции, словари

```
import os

def cars(mark, **arguments):
    profile_of_car = {}
    profile_of_car['mark1'] = mark
    for key, value in arguments.items():
        profile_of_car[key] = value
        return profile_of_car
cars2 = cars('subaru', 
             package='max',
             color='blue')
print(cars2)
os.system('pause')
```

**Выводится:
{'mark1': 'subaru', 'package': 'max'}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `return` в цикле `for`. Выполнение прекращается после первой итерации цикла.

```
import os

def cars(mark, **arguments):
    profile_of_car = {}
    profile_of_car['mark1'] = mark
    for key, value in arguments.items():
        profile_of_car[key] = value
    return profile_of_car
cars2 = cars('subaru', 
             package='max',
             color='blue')
print(cars2)
os.system('pause')
```